# Time Desynchronization (gravitational)? What if an eclipse was synchro between 2 altitudes on earth 1 million years before and is still synchro today?

Tags: reference-frames, relativity, earth, time-dilation, eclipse

2 events watched from 2 altitudes. Imagine an eclipse of the sun happens 1 milion years before (event 1) and it happens once more (event 2). (2 eclipses with 1 milion year interval watched from 2 altitudes).

2 **altitudes**: h1 (high); h2 (low)
   (sun is on a hypothetic line with h1 and h2)

**paces**H1: event1[*seenEclipse1*] at **h1**; event2[*seenEclipse2*] at **h1**; etc. AND

**paces**H2: **...**; event1[*seenEclipse1*] at **h2**; event2[*seenEclipse2*] at **h2**; etc.

**...**=one light travel **time** from h1 to h2

Question1: If event1 are **synchronized** (with clocks) between altitudes, are event2, etc. **synchrone**?

Question2: If all eventX are synchro, where is desynchronization?

Comment: E1 is seen at h1, he starts runing a clock (and see second/year 0,1,2, etc.).

E1 is seen at h2, she starts runing a clock (and second/year X,Y,Z, etc.).

He and she admit both clock started at 0 for E1 (admit X=0)

Will E2 (1;Y), E3 (2;Z), etc. be synchronized between altitudes (h1,h2) on earth?

Comment: Gravitational time dilation can be experimentally measured (and has been) by hobbyists using (fairly cheap) atomic clocks and GPS synchronization. The rest is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not entirely clear to me what the question is, I have a guess.

I suspect that you are imagining that by using an external event (the eclipses) you force the two clocks to agree on the elapsed time, and thus that if the clocks run a different speed it would make the second eclipse non-simultaneous at the two altitudes.

However, that's not what is predicted by relativity. Relativity predicts that the two clocks will (correctly!) measure a different number of elapse seconds between the two eclipses, which will be (to within lightspeed delay) simultaneous both times.

Of course, the geometry of the solar system forces the number of days (both solar and sidereal) to be the same to observers at both heights, but those observer measure a different number of second to the day.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Keep in mind that the second is no longer defined in terms of the mean solar day, but in terms of physical phenomena that can be measured in a small (i.e. local) laboratory anywhere in the universe.

Comment: You mean: h1: E1(sec0); E2(sec1)
h2: E1(X=sec0);E2(Y=sec1) OR: 
h1: E1(year0); E2(year1)
h2: E1(X=year0);E2(Y=year0.5)??? (seconds or years are not important)

Comment: I have no idea what that comment means.

Comment: E1 is seen at h1, he starts runing a clock (and see second/year 0,1,2, etc.). E1 is seen at h2, she starts runing a clock (and see second/year X,Y,Z, etc.). He and she admit both clock started at 0 for E1 (admit X=0)

Comment: So you mean after Event1 synchronized, there will be 1 million years for Event2 at h1 and 1 million years minus x minutes for Event 2 at h2? How h2(low) can become the first shadow today at 11h59 (admitting) before h1(high) today at 12h00 (admitting)?

Comment: You keep putting 'admit' or 'admitting'  into your writing in a way that has no obvious meaning to me. I think you are trying to be mathemtically precises, but you are using a system of writing that is unknown to me and is therefore failing to communicate anything. I've written what I mean fairly carefully. The first eclipse is seen by the high altitude observer immediately before it is seen by the low altitude observer and likewise for the second eclipse; but the (accurate) clocks of the two observer record different elapsed times between observations.

Comment: "but the (accurate) clocks of the two observer record different elapsed times between observations". Yeah, it is what we agree: 1 million years for h1 and 1 million years - 1 minute for h2! If Event1 is synchro then it is 1 minute before at h2 than at h1 (#propertime).